# How to change custom post type, blog post and page permalink by template?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

With `add_permastruct` i'm able to change the url of my custom post type.

Changing the `permalink_structure` option via admin interface working very well with `with_front => false` for my custom post types.

How do i change the URL of my blog posts via code?
`add_permastruct` is not changing the URL for post type `post` and `page`.

```
add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'rewriteUrls' ], 11 );

function rewriteUrls() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $version = '/product/%product%/version/%version%';
        $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%product%", '([^/]+)', "product=" );
        $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%version%", '([^/]+)', "version=" );
        $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'version', $version, false );

        $news = '/product/%product%/news/%postname%';
        $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'post', $news, false );
    }
```

Comment: What did you change the `permalink_structure` via Permalinks admin screen to? 
This answer for a [custom permalink just for posts question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617820/wordpress-custom-permalink-for-just-posts/15619416#15619416) is similar to what you're tried and is successful.

Comment: the crux of the matter is to do it via code. Using "/product/%product%/news/%postname%" as `permalink_structure` via admin interface works perfect but i'm not able to modify things in the admin interface of my customers. But i'm close to a solution - may answer my own question soon

Answer (score 1):

modify `post` works different than modify `page` than modify `custom post type` permalink. Here is how to modify all of them within your template code only and give the whole page a custom url structure.

### modify custom post type permalink

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewriteCustomPostUrls' );

function rewriteUrls() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $version = '/product/%product%/version/%version%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%product%", '([^/]+)', "product=" );
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%version%", '([^/]+)', "version=" );
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'version', $version, false );
}
```

### modify post permalink

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewritePostPermalink' );

function rewritePostPermalink(){
    global $wp_rewrite;

   $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure = "/product/%product%/news/%postname%";

}
```

### modify page permalink

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewritePostPermalink' );

public function rewritePagePermalink(){
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = "/product/%product%/page/%pagename%";
}
```

After that it's required to filter custom variables like `%product%` out of `get_permalink` response. For each type, post, page or custom there is a different filter. Heads up! `page_link` filter parameter 2 isn't the $post as with `post_type_link` and `post_link` but the page_id.

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'permalinkRewrite');
add_filter( 'post_link', 'permalinkRewrite' );
add_filter( 'page_link', 'permalinkRewrite' );

function permalinkRewrite( $permalink, $post ) {
    if (gettype($post) === "integer"){
        //page_link $post parameter is the ID instead of the object
        $post = get_post($post);
    }

    //removed code - get your variable here
    $product = "demoProduct";

    if ( $product ) {
            $permalink = str_replace( '%product%', $product->getSlug(), $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}
```

Finally, add some rewrite rules to catch the new permalink.

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'insertCustomRewriteRules' );

function insertCustomRewriteRules( $rules ) {
    $customRules                                         = [];
    $customRules[ 'product/([^/]+)/version/([^/]+)/?$' ] = 'index.php?version=$matches[2]'; //custom post type
    $customRules[ 'product/([^/]+)/news/([^/]+)/?$' ] = 'index.php?name=$matches[2]'; //post
    $customRules[ 'product/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/?$' ] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]'; //page

    return $customRules + $rules;
}
```